# I am one of the seven

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

In Night as in feather;

far right of forever;

common in parting,

awesome, and Startling;

twice first of upend;

all together, then blend.

---

Which one am I?

Comment: All formatting is intentional.

Comment: But there is only six...? Or is another line included (like the title)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really think you are:

> Wrath, one of the seven deadly sins as the title specifies.

In Night as in feather;

> **TH** is in both Nig*ht* and fea*th*er.

far right of forever;

> **R** is right at the far end of foreve*r*.

common in parting, awesome, and Startling;

> **A** is common in p*a*rting, *a*wesome, *a*nd St*a*rtling.

twice first of upend;

> **W**, pronounced 'double u', is twice first of *u*pend.

all together, then blend.

> Anagramming TH + R + A + W gives WRATH.

Note on the intentional formatting:

> The letters I, N and S are capitalised and these anagram to the seven deadly ones.